# Match all characters except a few using .(dot) in multiline string using Regex

Tags: python, regex

My input string is as follows :

```
The dog is  black 
and beautiful

The dog and the cat
is black and beautiful
```

I want to replace 'black' to 'dark' only when the cat is not described .
So my output should be

```
The dog is  dark 
and beautiful

The dog and the cat
is black and beautiful


pRegex = re.compile(r'(The.*?(?!cat)ful)', re.DOTALL)
for i in  pRegex.finditer(asm_file):
    res = i.groups()
    print res
```

With this , the 'black' is replaced in both the cases.

Is there anything wrong with the regex .
I am using python 2.7

Thanks

Comment: Nowhere in your text would `catful` match, yet that is what you are guarding against. There is no place that some text followed by `cat` is followed by `ful`. How are you replacing `black` with this pattern?

Comment: I was using (?!cat) as negative lookahead regex

Comment: Yes, but a negative look ahead does not work the way you think it does. It matches locations in the string. Almost all locations in the input qualify, except the spot just before `cat`. It does *not* alter how the `.*?` preceding the NLA matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regexp *cannot* describe a string based on a general negative expression ("not containing Z").  In your case you tried to express sth like "A string starting with X and ending with Y but *NOT containing* Z."  That *NOT containing* is not possible in regexp.  What your pattern resulted in to express was: "A string starting with X and ending with Y and containing at least one place which is not Z."  Which does not help.

I suggest to search for the more general expression and then test it using sth like `if 'cat' is in i:`.  That is straight forward and everybody is able to understand that.

A more sophisticated way could be to search for an alternative (OR) of two regexps, the first being one matching such expressions *with* `cat` inside, the other matching *all* expressions with that start and end part.  If you then capture both alternatives in different groups, you can easily decide on the group filled which alternative you've got (with or without cat).  But this only works if you can specify true separators between the groups which I figure you can't ;-)  Anyway here's an example of what I mean:

```
r = re.compile(r'(The[^|]*?cat[^|]*?ful)|(The[^|]*?ful)')
text = 'The dog is  black and beautiful | The dog and the cat is black and beautiful'
for i in r.finditer(text):
  print i.groups()
```

prints:

```
(None, 'The dog is  black and beautiful')
('The dog and the cat is black and beautiful', None)
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted "A string starting with X and ending with Y but NOT containing Z." . thanks for letting me know that it is not possible using regexp